# mx-auto works but not my-auto, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to vertically center this box to the middle of the page and I'm only able to center it in the middle using mx.

```
<style>

.jumbotron {
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #ffff;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="mx-auto">

<div class="my-auto">

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

<div class="jumbotron">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</p>

</div>
```

Comment: please provide valid code. your html is corrupt. better use something like [codepen](https://codepen.io/)

Answer (score 0):

"my-auto" needs its parent to have an explicit height like (height:100vh;) to make itself centered. consider this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mx-auto my-auto">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here "row" is the parent of "my-auto" class. so it should have an explicit height. so the css would be:

```
.row {
    height: 100vh;
}
```